# Where are Stringbuilder objects created?

Tags: java, string

Strings are immutable because they are stored in a constant string pool. So, where are stringbuilder objects created ? 
Say, I create two string builder objects

```
StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("abc");  
StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder("abc");
```

I will be ending up with 2 separate objects in heap memory right both containing the values "abc" ?

Comment: Strings are not immutable because there's a string constant pool, it's the other way around: A string constant pool is possible because strings are immutable.

Comment: @Hristo: They're not the same object at all. (In fact, they're not objects in the first place - they're variables, but they refer to different objects.) If you call `s1.append("foo")` then that won't affect the object referred to by `s2`.

Comment: @Hristo - Everytime two separate `StringBuilder` instances will be created for sure:)

Comment: @Hristo: I think not.  Doing this would mean that making changes to s1 will cause changes in s2, and the JVM would never know if this might happen in the future.  For this reason, I know that the JVM is smart enough **not** to make them refer to the same memory.

Comment: haha my bad guys. rookie mistake :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The immutability of strings has little to do with there being a constant string pool. Or rather, they *have* to be immutable for a string pool to be useful, but there doesn't have to be a string pool for them to be immutable.

Note that only compile-time constants end up in the string pool usually - unless you call `intern()`. So for example, if you have:

```
char[] x = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
String s1 = new String(x);
String s2 = new String(x);
```

then `s1` and `s2` refer to equal strings, but distinct objects.

Creating two `StringBuilder` objects simply creates two objects though. The exact implementation details of what's inside a `StringBuilder` can easily change between versions, and I don't know the details offhand, but it could easily be a `char[]` created from the string passed into the constructor. (I believe that's the case for JDK 1.6, anyway.)

Comment: is there any way to create s1 and s2 through a loop? or what if we need to create a lot of objects do we need to write one by one?

Comment: @NaoDesu: It's not really clear what you're asking about - I'd need to know what you wanted to do with the objects afterwards. I suspect you're best off asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str1 = "Java"
String str2 = "Java"
```

So, str1 and str2 are pointing to the same "Java" in literal pool.

```
String str3 = new String("Java");
String str4 = new String("Java");
```

str3 and str4 are not pointing to the same location but have separate memory allocated.

```
StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("abc");  
StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder("abc");
```

s1 and s2 do not point to same memory location.

So, whenever you say "**new**", it creates a separate memory for that variable.

You can test this by displaying their address on the Console.

Comment: In the second case why can't they point to the same location ? They are anyway strings and if you make them refer to a new string a new string object will always be created!

Comment: @phoenix, No, they don't point to the same location. You can check this by printing out the address of the two string objects

Comment: I know they don't point to the same object. But my question is why can't they? String s1 = new ("abc") String s2 = new ("abc"). So now even if s1 and s2 are pointing to the same object it wouldn't hurt right! Because the minute i assign s1 = "def" a new object is created .. so why doesn't the VM check to see if a string object already exists and assign any new string object to it? Basically I want to know why the discrepancy between the first method in your answer and the second one ? Why are 2 objects created for the second one ?

Comment: @phoenix, but why should the JVM check on that? I will give you an example. Say you are having 2 strings, one for first name and the other for last name. There is high probability that more than 1 person can have the same first name. Do you think JVM should have both their first names pointed to the same memory location? What if the 3rd person has a different first name? How does JVM handle that? Pointed to be noted is that whenever you are saying "new" in Java, it creates a separate memory location.

Answer (score 0):

The constant pool stores strings that are defined as literal (enclosed in double quotes) in the source code.
Non literal strings are not stored in the CP. They simply use an underlying `char` array, and make sure it is never written to.

A StringBuilder allocates such an array and then hands it over to a newly-created String object.

Comment: Apart from literal strings, also compile-time constant String expressions are stored in the constant pool, like `"Hello " + 5`.

Answer (score 0):

String literals that are created with double quotes are created in the String literal pool.

StringBuilder Objects are always created in the Heap memory.